# Arrays in If statements VHDL

Tags: if-statement, vhdl

I want to ask how do I write the if-statement for array of 8 bits in case it's all 0s
do I write it -take start as the controlling port-
IF START ='0';
OR
IF START ='00000000';

Comment: Neither. '0' in the character literal for the 0 character. '00000000' is not syntactically valid (See IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.6 Character literals, 15.8 String literals). As Renato shows without explanation in his answer the string literal "00000000" is used.The type of a string literal, a single dimensional array is determined by context (9.3.2 Literals). Without seeing the declaration for START a string of '0' characters is compatible with bit representing element types defined in packages standard, std_logic_1164, numeric_bit, numeric_std and fixed_pkg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if ***start*** is a **std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)** then you say:

```
if start = "00000000" then
.
.
.
```